# JetBrains Database Navigator plugin и его работа с проектами

Tags: sql, база-данных, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains

Добрый день!
Подскажите, если кто сталкивался, может ли данный плагин синхронизироваться с проектами? То есть, интересует возможность установления соединения с базой данных из проекта.

Answer (score 1):

По моему опыту plugin [Database Navigator](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/Database+Navigator) не может подключиться к БД `sqLite` эмулятора или устройства. Неободимо в `Android Studio` выбрать `Tools-> Android -> Android Device Monitor`. В открывшимся приложении найти БД и щелкнуть на иконку согласно [следующей инструкции](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140263/5330439). Тем самым мы сохраним БД эмулятора или устройства на Компьютер, на котором в свою очередь откроем её с помощью Database Navigator.

Проделывать операцию сохранения на компьютер и открытия в Database Navigator очень утомляет. Надеюсь, если есть способ более разумный, то сообщество поделится.

Для себя я выбрал  [следующее](https://github.com/TKlerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse). Установить можно расположив   [jar file](https://github.com/TKlerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse/releases) в `[Path to Android sdk folder]/sdk/tools/lib/monitor-[...]/plugins`.

Воспользоваться [этой инструкцией](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36883337/5330439) для просмотра. Обновление данных моментальное. Переключаетесь между `Android Studio` и `Android Device Monitor` (кнопка `refresh`).